# How do I extract this so it can be reused in other parts of my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this method in my book model but now I realize I need this in a category model as well:

```
def proper_user?(logged_in_user)
  return false unless logged_in_user.is_a? User
  user == logged_in_user
end
```

I now have this method duplicated in the books model and the category model. Both category and books has belongs_to :user and both have the user_id:integer in the table as well. I simply want to extract this somewhere where so I can its DRY.

i tried to put the method in application_controller.rb but it says undefined method `proper_user?' for #

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd want to be able to call this method like this:

`book.proper_user?(current_user)`

So it would work best to define it in each model rather then in User. This is best done by mixing in a module with the method:

```
module UserMethods
  def proper_user?(logged_in_user)
    # ... etc ...
  end
end
```

and including it in each model:

```
class Book < AR::Base
  include UserMethods

class Category < AR::Base
  include UserMethods
```

The module can go in a source file in config/initializers, or you can put it elsewhere and change `config.autoload_paths` in config/environment.rb to point to the location.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the module in lib. Initializers are a better place for configuration code, but for your own libraries, lib is most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is related to the User model, why not put it there?